# How to restrict default access on databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

Setting up a new SQL Server 2017 DB, I came to an unexpected behaviour.

When I create new users on my database, the user inherits all accesses of db_owner while on older servers, it only had few access rights.

I am wondering how I could have get to this situation.

As a comparison, I ran this script on “good” and “wrong” servers and attached the results:

```
EXECUTE AS USER ‘basicTestUser’
GO
USE myDb
GO
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_my_permissions(null, ‘server’)
GO

EXECUTE AS USER ‘basicTestUser’
GO
USE myDb
GO
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_my_permissions(null, ‘database’)
GO 

EXECUTE AS USER ‘basicTestUser’
GO
SELECT * FROM sys.fn_my_permissions(‘dbo’, ‘schema’)
revert;
```

[image: Good server sample]

[image: Wrong server sample]

Any idea how I could set it back to default and fix this?

Comment: FYI, that code won't work at all in SQ: Server, T-SQL doesn't support "smart quotes" (`‘’`) you have to use a "normal" single quotes (`'`).

Comment: All database users get the permissions of the public database role. By default these are VIEW
ANY COLUMN MASTER KEY DEFINITION,
VIEW ANY COLUMN ENCRYPTION KEY
DEFINITION, and SELECT permission on
many individual system tables. Check for any additional permissions assigned to the public db role.